# Angular.dart 1.X Default value in Select BOX

Tags: dart, angular-dart

How to define the default selected options in the select box. 
I'm able to display my options like this :

```
<select ng-model="selectedOptionId">
  <option value="">Select Option</option>
  <option ng-repeat="o in options" value="{{o.id}}">
    {{o.name}}
  </option>
</select>
```

But I am not able to define the default selected value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set it in your component's Dart file, since `selectedOptionId` is your model.

```
selectedOptionId = 3 //assuming o.id = 3 is your default
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer ! :)